# "Умер его отец (,) ста лет от роду". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, определения

И как ее объяснить? Причинное значение "ста лет от роду" здесь не учитывается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запятая факультативна. Зависит от смысла.

1.*Умер его отец ста лет от роду*.*Отец умер (когда? в каком возрасте?) ста лет отроду*.

2.*Умер его отец, ста лет от роду*. Отец каков? - несогласованное определение, содержит дополнительную характеристику, стоит после определяемого слова, ставится запятая.

При расстановке знаков препинания очень важно правильно определить тип второстепенного члена, выраженного существительным, поскольку это может быть не только определение, но и дополнение, обстоятельство.

Ср.: *Величественно вышла мать, в сиреневом платье, в кружевах. – Мать вышла в сиреневом платье, в кружевах.*

Если несогласованное определение, выраженное существительным, является обособленным, оно выделяется паузами.

Обособление несогласованных определений, выраженных существительным, часто является не обязательным, а факультативным. Если автор хочет дать дополнительную характеристику лицу, если обособление определения служит способом намеренного отрыва оборота от соседнего сказуемого, то такое определение является обособленным.

*Бабы, с длинными граблями в руках, бредут в поле* (Тургенев).

В данном случае И.С. Тургенев хотел подчеркнуть, что оборот с длинными граблями в руках относится не к сказуемому бредут, а к подлежащему бабы («бабы с граблями», а не «бредут с граблями»).

Обособленные несогласованные определения синонимичны придаточным предложениям.
Ср.: *Бабы, с длинными граблями в руках, бредут в поле. – Бабы, у которых в руках грабли, бредут в поле.*

Answer (score 0):

**Умер его отец, ста лет от роду.**

Запятая ставится **в обязательном порядке**, а то можно подумать, что у человек два отца.

**Это общий принцип**: согласованные и несогласованные определения имеют **ограниченную сочетаемость** со словами родства и именами, поэтому они, как правило, **обособляются.**